# How can I make my VS Code extension provide suggestions and syntax-highlighting for non-JS code in ES6 tagged template literal strings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql, vscode-extensions, tsserver

I’m working on a GraphQL extension for Visual Studio Code that implements syntax highlighting and auto-completion for GraphQL schemas and queries. It currently works on files ending with the `.gql` extension. However, a common GraphQL usage is to define inline queries inside JavaScript/TypeScript files, for instance:

```js
@connect(gql`user(id: 2) { name, email }`)
function MyUIComponent({ user }) { ... }
```

How could I support the highlighting and suggestion (autocompletion) features that my extension implements in ES6 (named) tagged template literal strings?

Comment: For anyone else also looking for a solution, a tracking bug is raised in the vscode github repo here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5961

Answer (score 1):

As linked in the comments under the question post, this is related to this github issue: [Extension providing language support in ES6 template strings #5961](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5961), which was resolved by [this comment by one of the maintainers, Matt Bierner](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5961#issuecomment-360890376):

> VS Code Extensions can now [bundle ts server plugins](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41113). This allows extension authors to write a vscode extension that adds syntax highlighting + intellisense for template strings.
>
> Two extensions are already making use of this: [...]

I did a quick google of `graphql ts server plugin` and found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-graphql-plugin.

Quoting from [its readme's "getting started" section](https://github.com/Quramy/ts-graphql-plugin#getting-started):

> First, confirm that your project has TypeScript and graphql(v15.x.0 or later).
>
> To install this plugin, execute the following:
>
> ```bash
> npm install ts-graphql-plugin -D
> ```
>
> And configure `plugins` section in your tsconfig.json, for example:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "module": "commonjs",
>     "target": "es5",
>     "plugins": [
>       {
>         "name": "ts-graphql-plugin",
>         "schema": "path-or-url-to-your-schema.graphql",
>         "tag": "gql"
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> It's ready to go. Launch your TypeScript IDE.

So to answer your question of "*How could I support the highlighting and autocompletion features that my extension implements in ES6 (named) template string?*", either you don't need to (just tell your users to include that TypeScript Server plugin), or you can find some way to integrate that into your plugin.

---

You could also try to take inspiration from the approach used by the [Template Literal Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=plievone.vscode-template-literal-editor) extension <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.

Quoting from its readme:

> Open ES6 template literals and other configurable multi-line strings or heredocs in any language in a synced editor, with language support (HTML, CSS, SQL, shell, markdown etc).
>
> Instructions: [...]

Other related tools:

This won't add suggestions, but for syntax highlighting in tagged template literal strings, there is the [comment-tagged-templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.comment-tagged-templates) extension by Matt Bierner.